# Can where clause condition be represented by another column

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have users enter the condistions for where clause for a table.  Now I want to use that clause to do select.  How can i do that?  Example,

```
Condition table ( ckey, condition)

1   fn like 'G%' and ln like 'B%'

Name table (nkey, fn, ln)
```

Query wanted

```
select * from Name where ... use condition in row 1 of Condition table .....
```

Comment: what programming language are you using?? Java, PHP, etc??

Comment: i don't want to do a round trip due to other reasons.  so i am looking for a solution within SQL itself.

Comment: The end result should be equivalent to: select * from Name where fn like 'G%' and ln like 'B%' but the condition is not a constant in advance.

Comment: see my answer... it will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Most DBMSes support a subquery inside WHERE, including [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery).

It's hard to say without more info, but you'll probably need a (correlated?) subquery on Condition table.

Comment: subquery is needed but i still can't bring the condition column as the condition of the where clause.  essentially, i want select * from Name where "using the resule of select condition from Condition where ckey=1"

Comment: @user1045358 I'm unclear what the problem is. Why can't you "use result of select condition from Condition where ckey=1"?

Comment: the result is a run time result and i can't write it in advance as the condition to the select * from Name.  It looks like having to use sp as Brandon suggests.

Comment: @user1045358 Ahhh... so you want to change the **text** of the SQL statement based on the result of another SQL statement? If so, you'll need to construct the SQL text yourself then execute it with whatever  facility your DBMS/API provides. This is called "dynamic SQL" and can be done either in the stored procedure or at the client level.

Answer (score 0):

See below

```
accept myID prompt "Enter ID : "
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id='&myID'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id= @Enter_ID)
```

see which one is working with you...

Answer (score 0):

One possible option would be to setup your condition table to mimic the table you're searching on.  Then you could simply join the tables on all fields.  In order for this to work you would have to default all columns in the condition table to '%' in case that condition isn't specified.

If your requirements are too complex for that to work, then another solution would be to use a stored procedure that generates dynamic sql based on what's in the condition table.

Comment: Make sure if you try the first solution though, that your joins look like this: " on Table1.field1 like Table2.field1 and Table1.field2 like Table2.field2".  Use 'like', don't use '='.

Comment: yes, the condition can be very complex since that's entered by the user.  would you elaborate on the solustion of using sp?

Comment: If possible I would actually use code (C#, VB, Java, PHP, or whatever you're using) to translate their conditions into SQL and just send that.  Even if you want to store their conditions in a table you can still retrieve that info in your language of choice and formulate the query you want to send.  But if you absolutely have to have a pure sql solution then pass a stored procedure the sql query you want to run along with a record ID for the record in the Conditions table that it should use to formulate the where clause with.  Then use the EXECUTE command to run the query string it formulated.